# Does といったところ translate to "approximately" or "at most" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

How would you translate the following sentence:

> 明日参加予定なのは、田中さん、林さん、川田さん、原さん**といったところ**です。

Is it either:

> According to tomorrow's schedule **only/merely/at most** Tanaka, Hayashi, Kawada and Hara will participate.

or:

> According to tomorrow's schedule **in all likelihood** Tanaka, Hayashi, Kawada and Hara will participate (but more participants are also possible).

Generally, would this also work with というたところ instead of といったところ?

Comment: Related (regarding といったところだ): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46513/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61887/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 新完全マスター N1 文法:

〜といったところだ is a grammar point that has a meaning of 程度は最高でも〜で、あまり高くない. It's used to show that the quantity of something isn't very much.

> 当地は夏もそれのほど暑くありません。最高に暑い日でも26、7どといったところです。
>
> この山歩き会では毎月山歩きを行っていますが、参加者は毎回せいぜい6、7人といったところです。

From a dictionary of advanced Japanese grammar, p633:

といったところだ is a phrase that the speaker uses to explain something in a brief/rough/approximate manner. (Not necessarily any nuance about being not very much... Just estimated. "I'd say that it's about....")

> この大学の学部生と院生は合わせて6000人といったところだ。
>
> Yankeesとred soxはほぼ互角といったところだ

(From a Mandarin textbook)
〜といったところだ can also be used to rephrase something using different/easier words to make it easier for someone to follow what you're talking about. Often used together with the ば form of verbs.

> 人気役者の浮世絵は、今日で言えばアイドル写真といったろころだ。
>
> 子供に人気の料理と言えば、カレーやハンバーガーといったところでしょう

You can see that in both cases, the speaker is taking something that they think the listener might not know about/be able to grasp (woodblock prints of stars from the 17th-19th centuries, children's tastes) and then gives a more accessible example to draw a connection (photos of idols, curry and hamburgers).

---

That in mind, whether or not there is a meaning of "merely" or not depends a lot on context.

He could be saying "four or five of us will participate tomorrow, according to the schedule" without any nuance of a judgement about how many or few people that is.

If this is a monthly/weekly whatever meeting and there are normally ten people, then you can infer that there's more of a "merely" feeling involved.

So your first translation is the more accurate one - just know that, depending on the context, you might not necessarily have a "merely" nuance involved.

I'm not sure if they're interchangeable or not - [ーといったところだvというところだ](http://www.edewakaru.com/archives/12438819.html) says they are, though.